# PyQt and dynamic label

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am still pretty new to python and the application I am writing I really want to keep the window open and change the text of a label when OK is selected. The text is stored in a config file, which is not the issue. I can bring it into a list or dictionary. I just not sure how to cycle through the text when the button is pushed. I can get the first and the last text. I just lost on the best process or logic to achieve this.

I have produced the application is tkinter, but was unable to achieve this functionality there either. I am using PyQt now because it has less limitations.

The code looks something like this:

```
import configparser
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
import sys
import random

appGlobal = {'dialogCount':0}
class GameDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        lblWBS = QLabel("lblWBS")
        lblDialog = QLabel("lblDialog")
        btnOK = QPushButton("OK")
        layout.addWidget(btnOK, 5, 1)

        lblDialog = QLabel()

        layout.addWidget(lblWBS, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(lblDialog, 1, 1)

        def npcDialog():
            lblDialog.setText(message[appGlobal['dialogCount']])
            layout.removeWidget(lblDialog)
            layout.addWidget(lblDialog, 1, 1)
            appGlobal['dialogCount'] =+ 1
        npcDialog()
        btnOK.clicked.connect(npcDialog)
        self.setWindowTitle("PALCDMS")

def kickoffMeeting():
    kickoff_meeting = config['kickoffDialog']
    global message
    message = []
    for name in kickoff_meeting:

        string_value = config.get('kickoffDialog', name)
        message.append(string_value)

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = GameDialog()
    dialog.show()
    app.exec_()

kickoffMeeting()
```

Comment: what is `config['kickoffDialog']`

Comment: using configparser, it looks in the config(textfile) with a section called 'kickoff' that contains the text to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach you can follow is to have simply a QPushButton, connect its click with a function where you do your behavior and that's all. I got some example as simple as I could, have a look on this and see if it makes sense.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton

import random


class Label(QLabel):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Label, self).__init__()

        self.letters = ['q','w','e','r','t','y']

        self.h_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.h_layout)

        self.label = QLabel('Random letters: _')
        self.btn = QPushButton("Roll")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.change_label)

        self.h_layout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.h_layout.addWidget(self.btn)

    def change_label(self):
        if len(self.letters)>0:
            self.label.setText(self.letters.pop(0))




if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_label = Label()
    main_label.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I think your biggest issue is your indentation. Don't know how new you are with python but that code you posted seems to have a pretty weird indentation. I had some issues to understand your logic.

Comment: Sorry, I probably messed up the indentation bringing the code into stack overflow. I will check it out. Thank you.

Comment: if it doesn't go right try using the code that I tried to do what I think you asked, see if it works and if it does how it could be applied to your example ")

Comment: I have adapted this to my code, for the most part. Only thing is, how would I move through that list without random? I want to cycle through the list to the end from left to right.

Comment: It will just depend on what way you want to walk in the list, it's just up to you, I just edited it to walk from the beginning to the end and keep in a loop. Have a look and see if it works. I just changed the `change_label` method.

Comment: The way I modified is just take the first element of the list, save it in a variable, put in the end of the list and set this variable as the text of the label, and keep doing that every time you click on the button.

Comment: Another way would be just have an index that you access the self.letters list and keep increasing this index in the way you want. And set the text of the label with `self.letters[index]` .

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much for the help. I may try the index version, because I only want to go through the list once and close the window after the last item.

Comment: Happy to know it worked for you. Just edited it again to loop just once as you need "). Or you can go for the index thing if you prefer and want more control over it.

Answer (score 0):

```
# App = QApplication([])
# Window = QWidget()

label = QLabel('label text', parent=Window)
label.move(300, 20)
label.show() # invoke "show()" to make your new widget visible.
```